# SAS concatenate number to each item listed in a string

Tags: sas

this maybe an easy quesition, but I just can't figure out the solution.

Suppose now I have a list of name say

```
%let name=helen mark anne lili;
```

Now I want to add number 2 to the end of each name, from which I wish to get

```
new_name = helen2 mark2 anne2 lili2
```

I tried to use the CAT function, but it didn't work

```
%let new=cat(&name.,'2');
```

Can anyone help me please ? Thank you!

Comment: CAT() will add that to the end of the full macro variable. You need to access each element and add the 2. Ideally, when you create the macro variable you can do that as well, or use a different method of storing your list that makes it easier to manipulate and use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the case of the *list* being properly delimited and spaced you can use `TRANSTR`.

```
%let name=helen mark anne lili;
%let name2 = %sysfunc(transtrn(&name%str( ),%str( ),2%str( )));

%put &=name;
%put &=name2;
```

Logs

```
NAME=helen mark anne lili
NAME2=helen2 mark2 anne2 lili2
```

Comment: Thank you! this is what I want. With just one line, problem solved!

Answer (score 1):

One option is to write a little macro to loop through the words and append the digit you want:

```
%macro myloop(list, dlm=%str( ));
  %local i length;
  %let length = 1;
  %let i = 1;
  %do %while(&length > 0);
    %let word = %scan(&list,&i,&dlm);
    %let length = %length(&word);
    %let i = %eval(&i + 1);
    %if &length %then
&word.2;
  %end;
%mend;

%let name=helen mark anne lili;
%put name = &name;

%let name2 = %myloop(&name);
%put name2 = &name2;
```

Answer (score 1):

The better solution here is to go back a few steps and create them at once.

ie

```
proc sql noprint;
select name, catt('new_', name) into :list1 separated by " ", :list2 separated by " "
from sashelp.class;
quit;

%put &list1.;
%put &list2.;
```

Answer (score 1):

one more way is to use prxchange and call symput.

brief explanation of prxchange.
\S+ means anything other than space

replace (\S+) with $1\L2

$1 first instance and we cannot add $12(12th position so I have to keep something between $1 and 2 hence i have $1\L2 \L is for lower and it has no impact as it is more for place holder

-1 indicates as many times possible

```
   %let    name = "helen mark anne lili";
   data names;
    new_name = prxchange('s/(\S+)/$1\L2/', -1, &name);
   call symput('new_name', new_name);
  run;

 %put &new_name;
```

Comment: `prxchange` can also be invoked directly in the macro environment with `%sysfunc`, and thus not require a data step.

Comment: you are right @richard. just wanted to keep it simple

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the Kiran's solution, you can actually do it using 100% macro code:

```
%let name=helen mark anne lili;
%put %qSysFunc(prxChange(s/(?<=\w)\b/2/, -1, %superQ(name)));
```

(?<=\w)\b means a word boundary preceded by a letter.